# Mathematica evaluates expression once, then returns the expression unevaluated

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Mathematica 8.0.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.2 does this: Quit the kernel and execute

```
MathieuS[MathieuCharacteristicA[  1, -(1/4)], -0.25`, 15.707963267948966`]
MathieuS[MathieuCharacteristicA[  1, -(1/4)], -0.25`, 15.707963267948966`]
(*
5.10119 10^-15
MathieuS[MathieuCharacteristicA[1, -(1/4)], -0.25, 15.708]
*)
```

That is, the first time it numerically evaluates the expression, while the second time it returns the unevaluated form.

Why? Or have I just spent too long staring at my screen and am doing something stupid?

Comment: Its likely you've spent too long looking at your screen, though I doubt it is the issue here. It happens on 7.0.1, also, and seems reproducible after rebooting the kernel.

Comment: Same result here (mma 7.0.1 on Windows 7).  Looks like a bug.

Comment: Reported as a bug.

Comment: @daniel and others, thanks for the replies. Does anybody have any suggested workarounds, other than solving the ode numerically?

Comment: I don't know if this is helps but as a workaround you could try running something like `MathieS[0,-0.25,0];MathieuS[MathieuCharacteristicA[1, -(1/4)], -0.25, 15.708]`. It seems that evaluating `MathieuS[a,-0.25,b]` for any other value of `a` temporarily resets `MathieuS[MathieuCharacteristicA[1, -(1/4)], -0.25, 15.708]`.

Comment: @heike thanks, I'll give that a try tomorrow.

Comment: It has been reported as a bug to the developers